# How to toggle a child div when i click on a parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to create a dashboard for my website and i'm a pretty begginer with javascript. In this case i'm trying to create a code for toggling a div, i tried to create a function to click in a div with the class "togglebox", and make his child div "togglebox-body" toggle, but it isn't working.

```js
$("main").on('click', '.togglebox', function() {
  const thisBox = $(this).children(".togglebox-body")
  thisBox.toggle()
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600;700&display=swap');

/* Common */

html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  --primary: #111;
  --gray-dark-1: #191919;
  --gray-dark--2: #161616;
  --gray-dark-3: #151515;
  --border: #222;
  --text: #555;
  --text-2: #969696;
  --white: #fff;
}

body {
  background: var(--primary);
  color: var(--white);
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 32px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 540px;
}

a,
p,
span,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

hr {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid var(--border);
  margin: 1.5rem 0;
}

hr {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid var(--border);
  margin: 1.5rem 0;
}

input,
textarea {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  background-color: var(--gray-dark-3);
  border: 1px solid var(--border);
  color: var(--text);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

textarea:focus,
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

button {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: var(--gray-dark-1);
  border: 1px solid var(--border);
  color: var(--text);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

footer {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: var(--text)
}

footer a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 16px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px var(--border);
  border: solid 3px transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  border-radius: 16px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px var(--border);
  ;
  border: solid 3px transparent;
}


/* Utilities */

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.justify-content-center {
  justify-content: center;
}

.justify-content-space-between {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.align-items-center {
  align-items: center;
}

.text-align-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.row-reverse {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.column {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.column-reverse {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.flex-grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.width-100 {
  width: 100%;
}

.margin-0 {
  margin: 0;
}

.margin-1 {
  margin: .25rem;
}

.margin-2 {
  margin: .5rem;
}

.margin-3 {
  margin: .75rem;
}

.margin-4 {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.margin-5 {
  margin: 2rem;
}

.margin-top-1 {
  margin-top: .25rem;
}

.margin-top-2 {
  margin-top: .5rem;
}

.margin-top-3 {
  margin-top: .75rem;
}

.margin-top-4 {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.margin-top-5 {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.margin-bottom-1 {
  margin-bottom: .25rem;
}

.margin-bottom-2 {
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

.margin-bottom-3 {
  margin-bottom: .75rem;
}

.margin-bottom-4 {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.margin-bottom-5 {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.margin-left-1 {
  margin-left: .25rem;
}

.margin-left-2 {
  margin-left: .5rem;
}

.margin-left-3 {
  margin-left: .75rem;
}

.margin-left-4 {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.margin-left-5 {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.margin-right-1 {
  margin-right: .25rem;
}

.margin-right-2 {
  margin-right: .5rem;
}

.margin-right-3 {
  margin-right: .75rem;
}

.margin-right-4 {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.margin-right-5 {
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.padding-0 {
  padding: 0;
}

.padding-1 {
  padding: .25rem;
}

.padding-2 {
  padding: .5rem;
}

.padding-3 {
  padding: .75rem;
}

.padding-4 {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.padding-5 {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.padding-top-1 {
  padding-top: .25rem;
}

.padding-top-2 {
  padding-top: .5rem;
}

.padding-top-3 {
  padding-top: .75rem;
}

.padding-top-4 {
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.padding-top-5 {
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

.padding-bottom-1 {
  padding-bottom: .25rem;
}

.padding-bottom-2 {
  padding-bottom: .5rem;
}

.padding-bottom-3 {
  padding-bottom: .75rem;
}

.padding-bottom-4 {
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.padding-bottom-5 {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.padding-left-1 {
  padding-left: .25rem;
}

.padding-left-2 {
  padding-left: .5rem;
}

.padding-left-3 {
  padding-left: .75rem;
}

.padding-left-4 {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.padding-left-5 {
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

.padding-right-1 {
  padding-right: .25rem;
}

.padding-right-2 {
  padding-right: .5rem;
}

.padding-right-3 {
  padding-right: .75rem;
}

.padding-right-4 {
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

.padding-right-5 {
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.gap-1 {
  gap: .25rem;
}

.gap-2 {
  gap: .5rem;
}

.gap-3 {
  gap: .75rem;
}

.gap-4 {
  gap: 1rem;
}

.gap-5 {
  gap: 2rem;
}

.box {
  background-color: var(--gray-dark-1);
  border: 1px solid var(--border);
}


/* Animations */

.scale-up {
  transition: 150ms;
}

.scale-up:hover {
  transition: 150ms;
  transform: scale(1.05);
}


/* Common */

.avatar {
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
}

.name {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.bio {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.link {
  padding: 15px;
  color: var(--text);
}


/* Blog Styling */

#post-wrapper {
  padding: 25px;
  color: var(--text);
}

#post-wrapper>hr {
  margin: 0;
}

.post-details {
  color: var(--text);
  font-size: 12px;
}

.post-title {
  color: var(--text-2);
  font-weight: 700;
}

.post-content {
  color: var(--text)
}


/* Dashboard */

.togglebox {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: var(--text)
}

.togglebox::after {
  content: "\25BC";
}

#link-manager-editor>a {
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="flex column">
  <div class="flex align-items-center justify-content-space-between">
    <h3 class="text-align-center">Dashboard</h3>
    <a href="#" class="scale-up">
      <img src="../assets/images/logout.png" alt="logout-icon">
    </a>
  </div>
  <hr>
</header>
<main>
  <section id="link-manager" class="box flex column margin-bottom-4">
    <div class="togglebox flex justify-content-space-between padding-3">
      <p>Gerenciamento de Links</p>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <hr class="margin-0">
      <div id="link-manager-editor" class="flex column gap-3 padding-3">
        <a href="#" class="link text-align-center box scale-up">Tutoriais de WordPress ‍</a>
        <a href="#" class="link text-align-center box scale-up">O Meu Encurtador De Link (Decreaser) </a>
        <a href="#" class="link text-align-center box scale-up">Projeto De Hospedagem De Arquivos Open Source </a>
        <a href="#" class="link text-align-center box scale-up">sarain.ag (Site Que Fiz No WordPress) </a>
        <a href="#" class="link text-align-center box scale-up">espacoviverpsicologia.com (Site Que Fiz No WordPress)</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="blog-manager" class="box flex column">
    <div class="togglebox flex justify-content-space-between padding-3">
      <p>Gerenciamento do Blog</p>
    </div>
    <div class="togglebox-body">
      <hr class="margin-0">
      <div class="flex column gap-3 padding-3">
        <div class="flex column gap-3">
          <form id="blog-search" class="flex gap-3">
            <input type="text" class="flex-grow" placeholder="Procure por algum post...">
            <button type="submit" class="scale-up">Buscar</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="flex column gap-3">
          <a href="#" class="box scale-up">
            <img src="../assets/images/blog-placeholder.jpg" alt="blog-post-featured-image" class="width-100">
            <div class="flex column gap-2 padding-4">
              <h4 class="post-title">O Decreaser v3 está finalmente pronto! Quais aprendizados eu tirei desse projeto?</h4>
              <div class="post-content">
                <p>O Decreaser foi um projeto que criei no começo de 2020 bem no começo da pandemia, onde est...</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Here is the JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/joaopcos/hd0ufbeg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<div class="togglebox">` doesn't have children with `class="togglebox-body"`. It should be `.siblings()`. Yes, this also means that `this` inside your delegate handler doesn't point to `<main>`, it points to `<div class="togglebox">`.

##### Structure

```html
<div class="togglebox">
   Heading
</div>

<div class="togglebox-body">
   Inner Content
</div>

<!- togglebox and togglebox-body are siblings here -!>
```

##### Updated Code:

```js
$(".togglebox").click(function(){
    const thisBox = $(this).siblings(".togglebox-body");
    thisBox.toggle()
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600;700&display=swap');

/* Common */
html{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    --primary: #111;
    --gray-dark-1: #191919;
    --gray-dark--2: #161616;
    --gray-dark-3: #151515;
    --border: #222;
    --text: #555;
    --text-2: #969696;
    --white: #fff;
}
body{
    background: var(--primary);
    color: var(--white);
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: 32px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 540px;
}
a,p,span,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5{
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-decoration: none;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5{
    line-height: 1.2em;
}
hr{
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid var(--border);
    margin: 1.5rem 0;
}
hr{
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid var(--border);
    margin: 1.5rem 0;
}
input,textarea{
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background-color: var(--gray-dark-3);
    border: 1px solid var(--border);
    color: var(--text);
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}
textarea:focus, input:focus{
    outline: none;
}
button{
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: var(--gray-dark-1);
    border: 1px solid var(--border);
    color: var(--text);
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
footer{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: var(--text)
}
footer a{
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px var(--border);
    border: solid 3px transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px var(--border);;
    border: solid 3px transparent;
}
/* Utilities */
.flex{
    display: flex;
}
.justify-content-center{
    justify-content: center;
}
.justify-content-space-between{
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.align-items-center{
    align-items: center;
}
.text-align-center{
    text-align: center;
}
.row-reverse{
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.column{
    flex-direction: column;
}
.column-reverse{
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
.flex-grow{
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.width-100{
    width: 100%;
}
.margin-0{
    margin: 0;
}
.margin-1{
    margin: .25rem;
}
.margin-2{
    margin: .5rem;
}
.margin-3{
    margin: .75rem;
}
.margin-4{
    margin: 1rem;
}
.margin-5{
    margin: 2rem;
}
.margin-top-1{
    margin-top: .25rem;
}
.margin-top-2{
    margin-top: .5rem;
}
.margin-top-3{
    margin-top: .75rem;
}
.margin-top-4{
    margin-top: 1rem;
}
.margin-top-5{
    margin-top: 2rem;
}
.margin-bottom-1{
    margin-bottom: .25rem;
}
.margin-bottom-2{
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
}
.margin-bottom-3{
    margin-bottom: .75rem;
}
.margin-bottom-4{
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.margin-bottom-5{
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.margin-left-1{
    margin-left: .25rem;
}
.margin-left-2{
    margin-left: .5rem;
}
.margin-left-3{
    margin-left: .75rem;
}
.margin-left-4{
    margin-left: 1rem;
}
.margin-left-5{
    margin-left: 2rem;
}
.margin-right-1{
    margin-right: .25rem;
}
.margin-right-2{
    margin-right: .5rem;
}
.margin-right-3{
    margin-right: .75rem;
}
.margin-right-4{
    margin-right: 1rem;
}
.margin-right-5{
    margin-right: 2rem;
}
.padding-0{
    padding: 0;
}
.padding-1{
    padding: .25rem;
}
.padding-2{
    padding: .5rem;
}
.padding-3{
    padding: .75rem;
}
.padding-4{
    padding: 1rem;
}
.padding-5{
    padding: 2rem;
}
.padding-top-1{
    padding-top: .25rem;
}
.padding-top-2{
    padding-top: .5rem;
}
.padding-top-3{
    padding-top: .75rem;
}
.padding-top-4{
    padding-top: 1rem;
}
.padding-top-5{
    padding-top: 2rem;
}
.padding-bottom-1{
    padding-bottom: .25rem;
}
.padding-bottom-2{
    padding-bottom: .5rem;
}
.padding-bottom-3{
    padding-bottom: .75rem;
}
.padding-bottom-4{
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
.padding-bottom-5{
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
}
.padding-left-1{
    padding-left: .25rem;
}
.padding-left-2{
    padding-left: .5rem;
}
.padding-left-3{
    padding-left: .75rem;
}
.padding-left-4{
    padding-left: 1rem;
}
.padding-left-5{
    padding-left: 2rem;
}
.padding-right-1{
    padding-right: .25rem;
}
.padding-right-2{
    padding-right: .5rem;
}
.padding-right-3{
    padding-right: .75rem;
}
.padding-right-4{
    padding-right: 1rem;
}
.padding-right-5{
    padding-right: 2rem;
}
.gap-1{
    gap: .25rem;
}
.gap-2{
    gap: .5rem;
}
.gap-3{
    gap: .75rem;
}
.gap-4{
    gap: 1rem;
}
.gap-5{
    gap: 2rem;
}
.box{
    background-color: var(--gray-dark-1);
    border: 1px solid var(--border);
}

/* Animations */
.scale-up{
    transition: 150ms;
}
.scale-up:hover{
    transition: 150ms;
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

/* Common */
.avatar{
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 96px;
    height: 96px;
}
.name{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.bio{
    font-size: 14px;
}
.link{
    padding: 15px;
    color: var(--text);
}

/* Blog Styling */
#post-wrapper{
    padding: 25px;
    color: var(--text);
}
#post-wrapper>hr{
    margin: 0;
}
.post-details{
    color: var(--text);
    font-size: 12px;
}
.post-title{
    color: var(--text-2);
    font-weight: 700 ;
}
.post-content{
    color: var(--text)
}

/* Dashboard */
.togglebox{
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: var(--text)
}
.togglebox::after{
    content: "\25BC";
}
#link-manager-editor>a{
    cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>joaopcos.xyz/admin/ — Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="flex column">
        <div class="flex align-items-center justify-content-space-between">
            <h3 class="text-align-center">Dashboard</h3>
            <a href="#" class="scale-up">
                <img src="../assets/images/logout.png" alt="logout-icon">
            </a>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section id="link-manager" class="box flex column margin-bottom-4">
            <div class="togglebox flex justify-content-space-between padding-3">
                <p>Gerenciamento de Links</p>
            </div>
            <div class="togglebox-body">
                <hr class="margin-0">
                <div id="link-manager-editor" class="flex column gap-3 padding-3">
                    <a href="#" class="link text-align-center box scale-up">Tutoriais de WordPress ‍</a>
                    <a href="#" class="link text-align-center box scale-up">O Meu Encurtador De Link (Decreaser) </a>
                    <a href="#" class="link text-align-center box scale-up">Projeto De Hospedagem De Arquivos Open Source </a>
                    <a href="#" class="link text-align-center box scale-up">sarain.ag (Site Que Fiz No WordPress) </a>
                    <a href="#" class="link text-align-center box scale-up">espacoviverpsicologia.com (Site Que Fiz No WordPress)</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="blog-manager" class="box flex column">
            <div class="togglebox flex justify-content-space-between padding-3">
                <p>Gerenciamento do Blog</p>
            </div>
            <div class="togglebox-body">
                <hr class="margin-0">
                <div class="flex column gap-3 padding-3">
                    <div class="flex column gap-3">
                        <form id="blog-search" class="flex gap-3">
                            <input type="text" class="flex-grow" placeholder="Procure por algum post...">
                            <button type="submit" class="scale-up">Buscar</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex column gap-3">
                        <a href="#" class="box scale-up">
                            <img src="../assets/images/blog-placeholder.jpg" alt="blog-post-featured-image" class="width-100">
                            <div class="flex column gap-2 padding-4">
                                <h4 class="post-title">O Decreaser v3 está finalmente pronto! Quais aprendizados eu tirei desse projeto?</h4>
                                <div class="post-content">
                                    <p>O Decreaser foi um projeto que criei no começo de 2020 bem no começo da pandemia, onde est...</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```